# UIButton with the tag property

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton

I am getting my UIButton with its tag bay name by using.

```
UIButton *mybutton=[[UIButton alloc]init];

mybutton=(UIButton*)[cell viewWithTag:5];
```

and with
    UIButton* mybutton=(UIButton*)[cell viewWithTag:5];

This is fine.but when i change it's text(with tag button) by using

```
[mybutton setTitle:@"hello" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

App Crashes with this error

```
[UITableViewCell setTitle:forState:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b6f540'
```

*** Call stack at first throw:

Any Solution??

Thanks in advance

Comment: The cell itself seems to have the tag 5. Make sure the button has a unique tag within the view hierarchy that you are going to search using `viewWithTag:` method. If you want a greater deal of resolution, you should add the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Comment: Why are you alloc/initing the UIButton and then setting it to the result of viewWithTag? That will result in a memory leak. If you're trying to set the button's tag just do `[mybutton setTag:5];`

Answer (score 2):

Use with your contentView

```
    mybutton=(UIButton*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:5];
```

Comment: this is correct. mark this as answered. you have to get cell.contentView to get its subView.